# 7404 IC Always outputting high

Tags: logic-gates

[image]I'm new to electronics, and it's my first  time using a hex inverter.
The following pins are connected:

- 1(Input A)-GND or VCC
- 2(Output A)-LED
- 7-GND
- 14-VCC

VCC is 5V, but whatever I do the output is high. It doesn't matter if I connect input a to 5v or 0v the LED still lights up. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: Well, it should not do that. Would you explain how you connect the input to 5V or GND, or how you connect the LED to output. Maybe there is a mistake. Take a photo of what you are trying to do. If you draw a diagram, the diagram may show what you intend to do, instead of what you actually do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! I have connected the input to 5V or GND simply using a wire, without any resistors.

Comment: That sounds correct but due to no available photo, there is no proof you are actually doing what you think you are doing. Also the wire may be broken or have bad contact so it does not work. Or you are using the wrong pins for input, output, or supplies. Everything is possible unless ruled out. Draw a diagram, or preferably, provide a photo of scenario that "does not work". For example, you don't mention about a resistor for LED, and don't mention if the LED is active high or low. If no resistor, the chip may have damaged due to overcurrent. Maybe it's the LED that's wired  wrong?

Comment: You could try another gate in the chip as a further check.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me! I just added the photo to the post. However, upon turning it on again the opposite happened. It’s constantly off…

Comment: @lukasm06 Is the LED in correct orientation? It looks like LED is between 5V supply and output, so LED should light up (if correct polarity) when input is high which should make output low. What is the value of the LED resistor? Do all wires and components make good electrical contact? Have you measured with a multimeter? If output is high, LED should be off, right?

Comment: If you’re going by the color of the line on the breadboard, it’s upside down. Everything makes good contact, will measure with a multimeter in the morning!

Comment: It hurts to see a black wire at VCC and a red one at GND...

Comment: @lukasm06 Normally, TI's recommendation is for a 1 kOhm resistor to Vcc for unused inputs or for inputs you want to tie HI. But for LS parts, which include diode inputs, they can be directly connected to Vcc. Looks like that may be an LS, so probably okay. That said, since you are directly driving LEDs, I'd recommend the 74LS06. Not the '04. The `06 can sink a LOT of current -- more than enough for an LED -- and can stand off up to 30 V, as well.

Comment: You might try moving to the next gate (in case the one you're using has gone bad).  Try using pin 3 as the input and pin 4 as the output. Try the LED in both directions if you are not sure of the anode/cathode.

Answer (score 1):

1. The LED is in backwards or should be connected to 0V instead of 5V: The anode should be connected to 5V for a high on pin 1 to light the LED. If you connect the cathode to 0V then a 0V on pin 1 will light the LED.
2. The red wire looks like it might accidentaly short to the resistor lead.
3. You have not tied off the unused inputs. I can't say for sure that this is responsible for your problem but [Note 3 in the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf) says, "NOTE 3. All unused inputs of the device must be held at VCC or GND to ensure proper device operation. Refer to the TI application report: Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs, literature number SCBA004."

The 74LS04 can sink 8mA, but source 0.4 mA. It is better to connect the anode to 5V cathode to the resistor, then calculate the resitor value for <=8mA. These inverters can be paralleled to get higher current.

The 7404 can sink 16 mA per output.

---

The OP indicates that ensuring the unused inputs are tied off solved the problem. Also mentioned in a comment the problem changed from always on to always off.

This indicates a latch is created by cross-coupling through the power rails.

A decoupling capacitor from pin 14 directly across the chip to pin 7 must be used to decouple the internal inverters from each other.

---

A comment by Hearth reminded me of the time that we received counterfeit LS chips from a local shop. They tested as HCT chips.

So I zoomed in on the state of Texas logo on the chip in the OP’s photo. Looking closely reveals a mermaid folded to look like the state of Texas. This is a counterfeit that looks like a TI chip to a glancing eye.

The 74HCT04 data sheet may be a better fit. I had to measure the input characteristics to be certain.

The CMOS inputs will be more sensitive when not tied off, so further explaining the OP’s problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was due to the inputs that weren't tied off! You've really helped me out here,

Comment: An original 7404 would be hard to find these days; for higher current capacity, a 74HC04 would probably be the way to go--the HC series is even easier to find today than the LS series.

Comment: So true @Hearth. And then there the counterfeiters. Look closely at the logo on the chip. The OP likely has a 74HC04. See my question update